# Add to timeline dialog doesnt appear at all

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am having some issues with facebook's open graph beta add-to-timeline function.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

I am following step by step instructions as mentioned in the text and video tutorial. As soon as I launch my app at https://strong-rain-3190.herokuapp.com/cooking.html the add to timeline button doesnt appear at all. I am not sure whats going on. Have tried many times but no luck.

Is anyone else having the same issue? or if there's any possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are logged into facebook already. 
You can test this by clicking on the Cook button and it would work.

Log out of facebook for the Add to timeline button to show up.